# How can I mock API / Module and test this svelte Component

Tags: javascript, svelte, vitest

Within my src/lib/apis directory I have a file named data.ts which contains the below code:

```
export async function getData(searchInput: string) {

return fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products', { method: 'get' }).then((res) => res.json());

}
```

within my src/lib/components directory I have a svelte component named ClientSearch.svelte with the following code:

```
<script lang="ts">

import { getData } from '../apis/data';

let searchInput = '';

let data: { [key: string]: any };

const handleSearch = async () => {

getData(searchInput).then((res) => {

    data = res; 

});  
};

</script>

<div>

<input type="text" placeholder="text search" bind:value={searchInput} on:keyup={handleSearch} />

{#if data?.products?.length}

{data.products[0].title}

{/if}

</div>
```

how can I test this ClientSearch.svelte component using Vitest? How can I write unit test to test the functionality that when a key is press that API is called and data that is fetched is displayed on the screen (I thought of mocking the api but failed to do so).

```
import { describe, expect, it, vi } from 'vitest';
import { render, screen, fireEvent, getByText } from '@testing-library/svelte'; 
import ClientSearch from '$lib/components/ClientSearch.svelte'; 
import { getData } from '../lib/apis/data';

vi.mock('../apis/data', () => ({ 
getData: vi.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ products: [{ title: 'Test Product' }] })) 
}));

describe('ClientSearch.svelte', async () => { it('should display the first product title when a search is made', async () => { const { getByPlaceholderText, queryByText } = render(ClientSearch);

    const input = getByPlaceholderText('text search');
    expect(input).toBeInTheDocument();
    await fireEvent.keyUp(input, { target: { value: 'example' } });
    console.log(queryByText('Test Product'));
});
});
```

I tried this out but it's printing null on console.

Answer (score -1):

When you press a key and expect some text to show up, remember Svelte needs a moment to catch up with your code's changes. It's not instant, especially in a test environment. After firing that keyUp event, you check for the result. Svelte's like, "Hold on, I'm not ready yet!"

Here's a little trick: give Svelte a second to breathe instead of checking right away. Use `await findByText('Test Product')`. This way, you're politely waiting for Svelte to do its thing and update the screen. It's like saying, "No rush, Svelte, I'll wait."

Your mock setup? Looks solid. You're telling the test, "Hey, pretend `getData` does this," which is excellent. Just ensure the rest of your test waits for Svelte's asynchronous updates. That way, when you check for 'Test Product', it'll be there, smiling back at you, instead of giving you the cold shoulder with a `null`.

Comment: Thanks @Dendalion await did the magic for me.